# Does Dask DataFrame work with large Pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I would like to use Dask to handle large dataframes.  However I get a memory error when I try to use it as follows.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'x': my_very_large_array})
ddf = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(df, npartitions=100)
```

I thought that Dask was supposed to handle larger than memory data.  What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that your code is failing before you get to Dask.  If you have a very large Pandas dataframe then you're already in trouble.  Dask can't help you in this case.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'x': my_very_large_array})      # maybe you're failing here
ddf = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(df, npartitions=100)  # rather than here
```

Instead, it's more common for people to read their data directly into Dask dataframes rather than route through Pandas.  They often use functions like `dask.dataframe.read_csv` or `dask.dataframe.read_parquet` to load their large datasets directly into Dask.  This helps them to avoid having to load all of their data into Pandas first, which would require that their dataset fit in memory.

More information about creating Dask dataframes is available here: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html

If you do encounter an error on the second line, then my guess is that you're at about 50% of your memory use, and Dask's splitting of your data causes a copy.  In this case the solution is the same, don't load your data into Pandas and then move it to Dask.  If your data fits comfortably in memory, use Pandas.  If it doesn't, then you should probably find ways to load it other than bringing it all into memory at once.